# How to use FIELDS(ALL) with SOQL PushTopic

Tags: soql, account, pushtopic

I'm trying to test out creating a PushTopic within the developer console using API v54.0. I want to create a PushTopic to retrieve all fields inside the `Account` object when a create, update, delete or undelete action has been committed.

```
PushTopic pushTopic = new PushTopic();
pushTopic.Query = 'SELECT FIELDS(ALL) FROM Account';
pushTopic.ApiVersion = 54.0;
pushTopic.NotifyForOperationCreate = true;
pushTopic.NotifyForOperationUpdate = true;
pushTopic.NotifyForOperationUndelete = true;
pushTopic.NotifyForOperationDelete = true;
pushTopic.NotifyForFields = 'Referenced';
insert pushTopic;
```

Error I'm getting:

```
System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error:

INVALID_FIELD, The SOQL FIELDS function is not supported with an unbounded set of fields in this API.: [Query]
```

Why is this Apex code not working as expected? Going by the [developer guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_streaming.meta/api_streaming/code_sample_java_create_pushtopic.htm) I thought this is what is meant to be done in order to accomplish this

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use an AccountChangeEvent trigger instead. The PushTopic API is for monitoring specific changes to records.

Comment: Specific changes to fields that are stated in the SOQL query?

Comment: @pragmaticlearner Yes. Though, thinking about it, I would guess this was done because an admin could change/add/delete a field, which could break things.